# Why aren't rows returned in the order of insertion?

Tags: oracle, select, insert, oracle18c

*Oracle 18c:*

I have 1000 rows of test data:

```
create table lines (id number, shape sdo_geometry);
begin
    insert into lines (id, shape) values (1, sdo_geometry(2002, 26917, null, sdo_elem_info_array(1, 2, 1), sdo_ordinate_array(574360, 4767080, 574200, 4766980)));
    insert into lines (id, shape) values (2, sdo_geometry(2002, 26917, null, sdo_elem_info_array(1, 2, 1), sdo_ordinate_array(573650, 4769050, 573580, 4768870)));
    insert into lines (id, shape) values (3, sdo_geometry(2002, 26917, null, sdo_elem_info_array(1, 2, 1), sdo_ordinate_array(574290, 4767090, 574200, 4767070)));
    insert into lines (id, shape) values (4, sdo_geometry(2002, 26917, null, sdo_elem_info_array(1, 2, 1), sdo_ordinate_array(571430, 4768160, 571260, 4768040)));
    insert into lines (id, shape) values (5, sdo_geometry(2002, 26917, null, sdo_elem_info_array(1, 2, 1), sdo_ordinate_array(571500, 4769030, 571350, 4768930)));
...
end;
/
```

Full data here: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4c6ff181fc155f5b38f01f6d9d4b468a)

When I select the data:

```
select 
    id,
    sdo_util.to_wktgeometry(shape) 
from 
    lines
```

...the data doesn't get returned in the order that I inserted it.

---

SQL Developer / on-prem db:

[image]

db<>fiddle:

[image]

I would have expected ID #1 to be the first row, and so on.

---

I know in reality, we would never rely on the order of the rows in the table. We would sort the data using `order by` if the ordering was important.

But I'm still curious, why wouldn't the data be returned in the order that it was inserted in? What's going on there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is: tables are basically “heaps" and the rows are inserted where ever they want.

Comment: Yep. There is no practical order to a result set unless you include it explicitly in your query with the `ORDER BY` clause.